# python get uploaded file stream (multipart/form-data)

Tags: python, forms, upload, stream, multipartform-data

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get the stream of an uploaded file.
I want to receive the file live and send it to a seperate file server. Python receive files like PHP, doesn't it?
 I get the temp-name and copy the file out of the temp-directory. But that would be very slow, to first receive the whole file and then reupload it to the external server.
Is it possible to get the stream,while the client is writing, and then send the data to the external server?

Comment: What web server and how is Python interacting with it? (A module, CGI, FastCGI?)

Comment: CGI, I think. I'm currently running XAMPP. I put the .cgi's in cgi-bin with the line "#!C:/Python27/python.exe" in the header.

Comment: I posted an answer to a WSGI based question, but many of the points are applicable to what you're doing - the difference is if you're using a CGI you would use sys.stdin instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407558/web2py-upload-a-file-and-read-the-content-as-zip-file/6407819#6407819

Comment: I tried this with a local client who sends the file in 1024 kb chunks

Comment: I tried this with a local client who sends the file in 1024 kb chunks.  The client repeatly send the chunks. But on the server there happened nothing. I tested this using the BaseHTTPServer of python and writing the "Received chunk" on sys.stderr. First I doesnt now exactly which arguments to give the cgi.FormValues(). Second, I think the cgi isn't called until the whole file is uploaded. Where's my fault?